# How we can hide the keyboard without pressing done button?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitextfield

I want to hide the keyboard without pressing the Return button in system keyboard, so that it automatically hides when I select the next text Field.

Here, I have four `TextField`s, placed inside one Custom Cells. They all have `tag`s associated with them. Then I put the custom Cell into `UITableViewController`.

First text field displays a `Date Picker`, using an action sheet. When I enter into the second text field, it shows the keyboard. My problem is that when I move to the next text field, the previous text field does not move away.

Comment: your adding done button by programmatically?

Comment: No,i did not taken any done button,i want to try to without press done & Return button in keyboard it will be resign automatically.while i changed textfields..

Comment: it will call textFieldDidEndEditing method for every textField by default if u are changing between textFields.

Comment: yes,i tried same way but still now kyeboard appearing..

Comment: what i did,in textfieldDidBingn i was taken condition like as if(textF.tag==1){}

Comment: what i did,in textfieldDidBingn i was taken condition like as if(textF.tag==1){ datepicker }else if(textf.tag==2){self.view endEditing:YES]; datepicker}else [textField1 resingfirstRespons];[textfiled2 resingfirstresponds];, so here 3rd textfiled shows

Answer (score 1):

Try this code ..in this touchesbegan it will be resign the keyboard when you wil touch on the screen ..and when you will select next filed it will call keyboard agin!

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
[usertextfiledobject resignFirstResponder];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try its textFieldDidEndEditing method to check the Enter button pressed.As soon it is pressed,it will call this method having code to resign keyboard.

```
[textField resignKeyboard];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this ..code no need to return keyboad of first textfiled..

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {

  if(textField.tag==1)
  {
     [self showAction sheet];
      return NO;

  }
  return YES;
  }

Comment: what happened ? you need mail id ?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

Try this method......if u go for next text field keyboard will popup again.